# Adding values to the end of a row if value meets criteria with pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, group-by, transpose

I am needing to get all values in one row if the meet a criteria.

Dataframe:

| Customer | Cost |
| --- | --- |
| Jane Doe | 100 |
| Jane Doe | 300 |
| Jane Doe | 10 |
| John Doe | 300 |

Needed Result:

| Customer | Cost | Cost1 | Cost2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jane Doe | 100 | 300 | 10 |
| John Doe | 300 | Nan | Nan |

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, try:

```
df_out = df.set_index(['Customer', df.index//3, df.index%3]).unstack()

df_out.columns = [f'{i}{j}' if j != 0 else f'{i}' for i, j in df_out.columns]

df_out = df_out.reset_index().drop(columns='level_1')

print(df_out)
```

Output:

```
    Customer   Cost  Cost1  Cost2
0  Jane Doe   100.0  300.0   10.0
1  John Doe   300.0    NaN    NaN
```